# Shifted bars in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, count, frequency

I created a bar graph in ggplot to show how counts in column `scheme` changed over time (i.e. from 2001 to 2016).

The x-axis is the `year`, the y-axis shows the frequencies (I used the `fill=`) to get the counts.

The data set consists of two columns (`year` and `scheme`) filled with character values:

```
year scheme

2016 yes
2016 yes
2016 yes
2016 yes
2015 yes
2015 yes
2014 yes
2013 yes
....
2006 no
2006 no
2006 no
2006 no
2005 no
2005 no
2004 no
2003 no
2002 no
2002 no
2001 no
2001 no
```

My code:

```
a <- ggplot(s) + 
    stat_bin(aes(x=year, fill=scheme, group=scheme), geom="bar", position = "dodge",bins=30)
b <- a + scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(2001:2016), labels = factor(2001:2016))
c <- b + theme(axis.text.x=element_text(size = 10, colour = "black"))
```

The graph:

[image: The bar graph in ggplot]

The problem I have is that the bars are shifted in the graph for no reason. You can recognize it by looking at the x-axis and the `year` label. The bars are moved too much to the left (e.g.2007) or to the right (2002).

I have no clue why it happened and how can I fix it? Any type of suggestions is very much welcome.

Comment: I think scale_x_continuous is causing the issue. Would you try removing that and then alter the aesthetics to `x = factor(year)`?  Alternatively, you could try setting the scale to a date with the scale_x_date option -`scale_x_date(format = "%Y")` might work.

Answer (score 3):

Use `binwidth = 1` instead of `bins = 30`.  When you specify there should be 30 bins, you're asking for the years to be broken into the segments whose endpoints are sequential values in `seq(2001, 2016, length.out = 30)`.

All the weird gaps are from the bins which didn't include a whole number.

Comment: Thank you so much. I changed only `bins=30` to `binwidth = 0.5` and it looks exactly as I wanna have it.